# SIGSEGV in optimized version of code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, segmentation-fault

My knowledge of the intel instruction set is a bit rusty.  Can you tell me why I might be getting a segmentation fault in the optimized version of my function (bonus points if you can tell me why I don't get it in the -O0 build of the code.

It's C code compiled by GCC 4.1.2.

Here is the result of GDB's "disas" command at the crash:

```
   0x00000000004263e5 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00000000004263e9 <+4>:     movsd  %xmm2,(%rsp)
   0x00000000004263ee <+9>:     divsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x00000000004263f2 <+13>:    callq  0x60f098 <log@plt>
=> 0x00000000004263f7 <+18>:    andpd  0x169529(%rip),%xmm0        
   0x00000000004263ff <+26>:    movsd  (%rsp),%xmm1
   0x0000000000426404 <+31>:    ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm1
   0x0000000000426408 <+35>:    seta   %al
   0x000000000042640b <+38>:    movzbl %al,%eax
   0x000000000042640e <+41>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000426412 <+45>:    retq
```

And here's the original source of the function:

```
char is_within_range(double a, double b, double range) {
  double ratio = a / b;
  double logRatio = fabs(log(ratio));
  return logRatio < range;
}
```

For reference here's the non-optimized version of the code:

```
   0x00000000004263e5 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004263e6 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004263e9 <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x00000000004263ed <+8>: movsd  %xmm0,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000004263f2 <+13>:    movsd  %xmm1,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x00000000004263f7 <+18>:    movsd  %xmm2,-0x28(%rbp)
   0x00000000004263fc <+23>:    movsd  -0x18(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000426401 <+28>:    divsd  -0x20(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000426406 <+33>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x000000000042640b <+38>:    mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000042640f <+42>:    mov    %rax,-0x30(%rbp)
   0x0000000000426413 <+46>:    movsd  -0x30(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000000000426418 <+51>:    callq  0x610608 <log@plt>
   0x000000000042641d <+56>:    movapd %xmm0,%xmm1
   0x0000000000426421 <+60>:    movsd  0x16b6b7(%rip),%xmm0
   0x0000000000426429 <+68>:    andpd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x000000000042642d <+72>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000426432 <+77>:    movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm1
   0x0000000000426437 <+82>:    movsd  -0x28(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x000000000042643c <+87>:    ucomisd %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000000426440 <+91>:    seta   %al
   0x0000000000426443 <+94>:    movzbl %al,%eax
   0x0000000000426446 <+97>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000426447 <+98>:    retq
```

Comment: Have you checked the differences with the non-optimized code (assembly output)? If so, can you post it as well?

Comment: I don't think the input actually matters...

Comment: That version of GCC is > 4.5 years old. This could be an optimization bug in the old version of GCC.

Comment: Why would that instruction cause a seg fault in the first place?  I assume it's something to do with the million+ addressing modes, but maybe someone could weight in?

Comment: Output from `gcc -S` would probably be more helpful than the output of a Gdb disassembly.

Comment: Presumably you don't have access to `0x169529(%rip)`. I've compiled this code with both `-O0` and `-O3` in GCC 4.5.2, and both optimization levels use `andpd %xmm1, %xmm0`.

Comment: Have you tried running through valgrind. The error may be there in both versions but the optimization just makes it happen more often.

Comment: Do you have `#include <math.h>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=> 0x00000000004263f7 <+18>:    andpd  0x169529(%rip),%xmm0        
   0x00000000004263ff <+26>:    movsd  (%rsp),%xmm1
```

When the `andpd` instruction takes a memory operand, it's required to be aligned to a 16-byte boundary.

For `%rip`-relative addressing, the offset is applied to the address of the following instruction.  So, here, the memory operand is at `0x4263ff + 0x169529 = 0x58f928`, which is not 16-byte aligned.  Hence the segfault.

The compiler is directly generating code for `fabs()`, using an AND with an appropriate bit mask to clear the sign bit; the bit mask constant value should have been placed at an appropriate offset in a sufficiently aligned data section, but hasn't been.  This could be a bug in that (old) version of GCC, or could conceivably be a linker-related issue somewhere else.

Comment: The follow up to this, is that your answer is spot on, it turned out to be a linker bug in a non-standard linker that we're using.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to crash after the call to the `log` function:

```
callq  0x60f098 <log@plt>
```

So there's maybe a problem with the `fabs` implementation, using `-O0`.

Have you tried:

```
double logRatio = log(ratio);
logRatio = fabs(logRatio);
```

This may generate a different assembly output, and you may get additional infos about the crash.

As an alternative, you may replace the `fabs` call with something like:

```
double logRatio = log(ratio);
logRatio = (logRatio < 0) -logRatio : logRatio;
```

You may have precision issues with that, but that's not the point here...

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using `gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)`, here's the generated assembly:

```
Dump of assembler code for function is_within_range:
0x0000000000400580 <is_within_range+0>: divsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
0x0000000000400584 <is_within_range+4>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400588 <is_within_range+8>: movsd  %xmm2,(%rsp)
0x000000000040058d <is_within_range+13>:        callq  0x400498 <log@plt>
0x0000000000400592 <is_within_range+18>:        andpd  358(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x400700
0x000000000040059a <is_within_range+26>:        xor    %eax,%eax
0x000000000040059c <is_within_range+28>:        movsd  (%rsp),%xmm1
0x00000000004005a1 <is_within_range+33>:        ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm1
0x00000000004005a5 <is_within_range+37>:        seta   %al
0x00000000004005a8 <is_within_range+40>:        add    $0x8,%rsp
0x00000000004005ac <is_within_range+44>:        retq
```

It appears to be almost the same, but I do not get a crash. I think you'll need to provide us with your compiler flags, and details of your processor and GLIBC version, and the values of `a`, `b`, and `range` that crash for you, as the issue is almost definitely with the `log` call.